# Replace Require statement with Import statement causing error

Tags: typescript, import, require

I'm trying to use [Ajv](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv) (and I'm using typescript).

```
import { Ajv } from "ajv";

let ajv = new Ajv({allErrors: true});
```

Just wondering why it is giving this error:

> [ts] 'Ajv' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

I'm using it the same as the documentation does:

```
var Ajv = require('ajv');
var ajv = new Ajv(); // options can be passed, e.g. {allErrors: true}
var validate = ajv.compile(schema);
var valid = validate(data);
if (!valid) console.log(validate.errors);
```

But I use import instead of require so I'm not setting the variable, so i guess this is causing the error. How would I define the variable for usage when using `import` instead of `require`?

All code:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Http, Headers, Response } from "@angular/http";
import { Configuration } from "../shared/configuration.model";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Rx";
import { Ajv } from "ajv";

@Injectable()
export class ValidateJSONSchemaService {

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    public valJson(json, schemaFile: string) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.http.get(schemaFile)
                .toPromise()
                .then(fileContents => fileContents.json())
                .then((schema) => {
                    let ajv = new Ajv({allErrors: true});
                    ajv.validate(schema, json) ? 
                    resolve() :
                    reject(new Error("JSON does not conform to schema: " + ajv.errorsText()));
                }, err => reject(
                    new Error("Unable to get schema file contents:" + err))
                );
        });
    };
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `import * as Ajv from 'ajv'`?

Comment: @elclanrs That worked thanks

Comment: @elclanrs, can you upgrade your comment to an answer so others can find it? Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As @elclanrs said, use `import * as Ajv from 'ajv'`

Not trying to take credit, but it's been a year and I almost missed the answer because there was nothing marked as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add in Node 10.x with TS 3.45 and Angular 8.x I had to do it using

```
// @ts-ignore
import Ajv = require('ajv');
```

*note @ts-ignore as TSlint will complain about importing modules this way*

Then later on in my code I could use it as normal.

```
const ajv = new Ajv();
```

using `import * as Ajv from 'ajv'` angular would not build correctly, as I kept seeing this error

```
 error TS2351: Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.
```

The Typescript complier recommends therefore you resolve using this import method

```
 Type originates at this import. A namespace-style import cannot be called or constructed, and will cause a failure at runtime. Consider using a default import or import require here instead.
```

Hopefully that will help someone else using angular 8.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to import it for a node project and I've imported it as:

```
import Ajv from 'ajv'
```

and then, you can use it as:

```
...
let ajv = new Ajv({allErrors: true});
...
```

I'm using node v12.8.1.